# Error import six

Tags: python

I'm getting an error message while running python script. Below is the error message.  Appreciate help to resolve the issue.

When I import "six.moves.http_client import HTTPConnection" it works, issue is when I import HTTPSConnection

```
>>> from six.moves.http_client import HTTPSConnection
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSConnection'
>>> from six.moves.http_client import HTTPSConnection 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSConnection'
```

Comment: `from six.moves import http_client; print dir(http_client); print http_client.__file__` - does dir include `HTTPSConnection`? is `__file__` reasonable?

Comment: Also, something odd is happening in your environment, because this works perfectly fine in my environment.

Comment: I dont see HTTPSConnection in the dir and the __file__ is /usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py . How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: It might be helpful to learn about your installation. We can only see from this comment that it seems to be Linux and it seems to be python3.5. Please provide at least: `import sys; print sys_implementation` and the printouts that Rogalski was asking for. Please provide these prints verbatim, and provide it in the question so that potential answerers do not have to search for additional information in hardly formatted comments.

Comment: I replied back to Rogalski that I dont see HTTPSConnection and the file is /usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py.                                                  Here is the output - print (sys.implementation)
namespace(cache_tag='cpython-35', hexversion=50659824, name='cpython', version=sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0))